# Why don't all free particles lose their kinetic energy?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle, boundary-conditions, action

I'm currently studying Action. I've been reading about how a particle has particular probabilities of ending at an infinite number of events.

Say I have a free particle that isn't experiencing any external forces (no potential, or friction). I give it a particular kinetic energy, whilst it is at some arbitrary event A. Why doesn't the particle stay at position A, "lose" its kinetic energy and reduce the action to a minimum? Why does it travel in a particular straight line? You can't argue from conservation laws since they are dependent on the idea of the stationary action principle.

I'm curious to know the answer, cheers!

Comment: Newton's first law.

Comment: Lose it to what? The energy has to go somewhere.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Particles do not minimize their action. Instead, they minimize their action given certain boundary conditions. We can only apply the action principle when we know the start and end points ahead of time.

If we know that a particle will be at location $x_i$ at time $t_i$ and that it will be at location $x_f$ at time $t_f$, then the particle takes a path of least (or stationary) action between those two points. Standing still generally isn't an option because $x_i \neq x_f$ in most cases. The way the problem is set up, the particle is forced to move, simply by hypothesis, before we even being trying to minimize the action. 
If $x_i = x_f$ and you have a free particle, then indeed the action is minimized by staying still, which is exactly what the particle does.

The free particle problem can be solved with relativity. We can transform into a frame where $x_i = x_f$, and in this frame the particle is stationary. Transforming back, the particle moves at constant velocity in the original frame.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'm still unsure on your answer though - A system has a probability of ending up at an event (starting from event A), so how could you be ever sure whether the final event IS event B? Then, be able to calculate the minimum action.

Comment: @charl1e the problem is set up assuming that we do know that the final event is event B. Consider this problem as the following: the observer measured at time $t_i$ the particle at position $x_i$. After some time, at time $t_f$, the observer measured that the particle is at $x_f$. The problem to solve is _how the particle moved from $x_i$ to $x_f$_. And the stationary action principle gives us the equations of motion, which we can solve to find the answer — the trajectory, given the boundary conditions.

Comment: @Ruslan Is it set up assuming we know the final event is indeed event B? Any object is made up of particles (e.g. electrons), and particles alone seem have a much larger probability of ending up at a different event, so how could I ever be absolutely sure it ends up at a final event B?

Comment: @charl1e usually you don't have to specify what event is event $B$. You just assume that it exists. Then you get your equations of motion, and after that you can transform the problem from boundary value problem to initial value problem — this is how Newton's laws are recovered from stationary action principle.

Answer (score 4):

Since it's a quiet Sunday morning let me dust off my brain cells and see if I can remember how to do this. We start by noting that if the initial and final positions for the particle as $\mathbf{r}(t_1)$ and $\mathbf{r}(t_2)$, then the action is:

$$ S[\mathbf{r}(t)] = \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \tfrac{1}{2}m\dot{\mathbf{r}}^2 $$

We'll make the change $\mathbf{r} \rightarrow \mathbf{r} + \delta\mathbf{r}$ in which case the action becomes:

$$ S[\mathbf{r} + \delta\mathbf{r}] = \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \tfrac{1}{2}m \left(\dot{\mathbf{r}}^2 + 2\dot{\mathbf{r}}\cdot\delta\dot{\mathbf{r}} + \delta\dot{\mathbf{r}}^2\right) $$

So the change in the action is:

$$ \delta S = \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \tfrac{1}{2}m \left(2\dot{\mathbf{r}}\cdot\delta\dot{\mathbf{r}} + \delta\dot{\mathbf{r}}^2\right) $$

and we do the usual trick with infinitesimals of ignoring squared and higher power terms to give:

$$ \delta S = m\int_{t_1}^{t_2}  \dot{\mathbf{r}}\cdot\delta\dot{\mathbf{r}} $$

The next step is a sneaky trick that only the more able physicists will guess without being told (I didn't :-). We use integration by parts:

$$ \int u\dot v\, dt= uv\bigg|_{\text{end points}} - \int \dot u v\, dt $$

with $u = \dot{\mathbf{r}}$ so $\dot u = \ddot{\mathbf{r}}$, and $\dot v = \delta\dot{\mathbf{r}}$ so $v = \delta\mathbf{r}$, and this gives us:

$$ \delta S = \left[ m\dot{\mathbf{r}}\cdot\delta\mathbf{r} \right]_{t_1}^{t_2} - m \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \ddot{\mathbf{r}}\cdot\delta\mathbf{r} $$

But the endpoints are fixed so $\delta\mathbf{r}(t_1) = \delta\mathbf{r}(t_2) = 0$ and the first term is zero giving:

$$ \delta S = -m \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \ddot{\mathbf{r}}\cdot\delta\mathbf{r} $$

At the extremum of the action $\delta S = 0$, so the integral must be zero. However $\delta\mathbf{r}$ can be anything as any variation of $\mathbf{r}$ is allowed. This means the integral can only be zero if $\ddot{\mathbf{r}} = 0$, and after all this pain we end up with Newton's first law:

$$ \ddot{\mathbf{r}} = 0 $$

So the free particle has a constant velocity and therefore constant kinetic energy.

Since someone will surely mention it (though it's somewhat beyond my personal level in this area) [Noether's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem) tells us that if the action is not time dependent then the energy is conserved. So we didn't really need all this working to conclude that the kinetic energy can't change.

Comment: I keep on finding "dependant" instead of "dependent" in your answers, John ;) I also improved the exposition of integration by parts (feel free to rollback if you disagree that this is clearer).

Comment: @Danu: Spelling and grammar were beaten into me at public school, but there are still a few words with which I have a mental blank spot. Or maybe it's senility creeping in. Oh well :-)

Comment: That's what you have me for ;)

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the reply bud! I haven't read through the maths yet, but I do appreciate the response :)